# Is Jesus the NEW light of the world?

Tags: jesus

Lucifer, as the favored archangel, was given a name meaning « Light bringer ». Jesus had been heralded as the light of the world; ie: bringing a light to the darkness, and Lucifer’s influence is the reason we needed a messiah.
I don’t understand why the messiah would be referenced to as the same as the evil one. Can someone parse it out for me ?
Edit: in Isaiah 14:12 (quoted from the King James Version).

How art thou fallen from heaven, O Lucifer, son of the morning! how art thou cut down to the ground, which didst weaken the nations!
and this passage, Luke 10:18 (KJV):

And he said unto them, I beheld Satan as lightning fall from heaven.

I’ll add from John 8:12, ‘Again Jesus spoke to them, saying, “I am the light of the world. Whoever follows me will not walk in darkness, but will have the light of life.”
But there are many times he refers r Himslef as the Light of the world.

Comment: Please provide the verse that you base this question on.

Comment: @Scamp Lucifer is a name of the planet Venus. Perhaps, since Venus is a goddess of sexuality which besides decent dimension of sexuality includes also sinful and lewd one (Ἀφροδιτής γαϊκή), so, this name perhaps that's why by association was given to a fallen angel turned into demon. Oh, those inscrutable associations! It has nothing to do with our Lord.

Comment: There is a light that is a false light. _If the light that is in thee be darkness, how great is that darkness._ But there is also light which the true Light.